# Slow Performance on EntityManager.getResultList()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

We use Hibernate + Spring boot in our web application, we've performance issue with EntityManager to execute a select query.  The query should return 20 rows and is executed < 1 s in DBArtisan.  However, the same query is executed for 9 seconds in the code:

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> totalCriteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<M> totalRoot = totalCriteriaQuery.from(modelClass);
        totalCriteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(totalRoot));
        if (searchCriteria != null) {
            totalCriteriaQuery.where(whereBuilder.build(searchCriteria, criteriaBuilder, totalRoot));
        }
        TypedQuery<Long> totalQuery = em.createQuery(totalCriteriaQuery);
        contentQuery.setFirstResult(pageRequest.getOffset());
        contentQuery.setMaxResults(pageRequest.getPageSize());
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();
        List<M> resultList = contentQuery.getResultList();
        stopWatch.stop();
        System.out.println("Nano seconds: "+ stopWatch.getNanoTime());
```

I'm looking for the cause or any suggestions about the performance using EM.

Comment: Comparing a SQL execution time with a HSQL and returning objects is comparing apples and oranges.  Depending on your database using paging is very slow, also why do you use paging it is a count which always turns a single result.

Comment: Can you post the query that you ran in DBArtisan and the one that JPA is generating. Unless they are completely different queries, there should be any significant difference in execution times.

Comment: This is the generated JPA query (with slight modifications in order to run in DBArtisan): select * from dummytable as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.final_decision is null order by generatedAlias0.id asc  -- it's returns 20 rows

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing poor performance, you should try profiling the code to see where the performance issues really lie. I would recommend using JProfiler for this purpose, it gives a very clear result, reporting even the caller functions.

Have you tried caching the Query, it may also help here as you are using Hibernate + Spring configuration. I'd recommend having a look at this page if you want to improve your performance [JPA Performance Tuning](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html).

P.S. From my own experience, if performance is your first preference try using plain JDBC rather than EM.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes, Criteria API uses OFFSET and LIMIT for pagination but those [don't scale](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) for large offset values.

So the further you go with the pages, the slower the query will become, but that's a relational database shortcoming.

You can use [key-set pagination](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) and fetch the ids first and use those to fetch entities afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my entity has a join column with another table, the actual query generated by hibernate contains multiple sub queries. I've the following annotation for that column and once I change to LAZY, it speeds up as expected, but not sure what's implication of changing the FetchType.

```
 @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```